# How can I prove an equation has a certain number of real roots?

Tags: equation-solving, numerics, proof

I have this code

```
NSolve[1-(b/r)^2-g^-2*(2/15 * Σ^9 (1/(r-1)^9-1/(r+1)^9-9/(8r) (1/(r-1)^8-1  
       /(r+1)^8)) - Σ^3 (1/(r-1)^3-1/(r+1)^3-3/(2r) (1/(r-1)^2-1  
       /(r+1)^2))) == 0, r, Reals]
```

I want to prove that for any values of g, b, Σ, I will find, for r, only 4 real roots. The others will be complex.

Any ideas?

Comment: This seems to be a question about mathematics instead of *Mathematica* -- is that right?

Comment: @MichaelE2 , but i have to use wolfram mathematica to do that, use the commando SOLVE or FindRoot , i dont know exactly

Comment: Try `Numerator[Together @ yourfunction] /. r^n_ :> r^(n/2)` and see if you can prove only two positive real roots (ruling out `r == 0` because there is a factor of `r` in the denominator).

Comment: Are you sure it has only real roots? One easy thing to do would be to calculate the roots for lots of different g,b,sigma values and see if you ever get more than 4 real ones. If yes, then no need to try and prove it. If no, then you can be more confident that the result you want really exists.

Comment: @bill , i cant do that, put some values ... i try to do it, i a get only four real roots, the othes is complex. i want to prove generally , for all values of sigma, g and b ...

Answer (score 12):

We needn't guess many (thousands) cases in order to verify the underlying statement if we harness some handy *Mathematica* functions like `CountRoots`, `RegionPlot3D` or `Manipulate`.

At first, we can observe that, the equation can be easily transformed to a polynomial type by an appropriate multiplication (applying `Expand` on the left hand side of the equation we can see an obvious choice for a multiplying factor  `r^2 (r + 1)^9 (r - 1)^9 g^2`).

```
FullSimplify[ (1 - (b/r)^2 - g^-2 (2/15 Σ^9 (1/(r - 1)^9 - 1/(r + 1)^9 - 9/(8 r) (1/(r - 1)^8
               - 1/(r + 1)^8)) - Σ^3 (1/(r - 1)^3 - 1/(r + 1)^3
               - 3/(2 r) (1/(r - 1)^2 - 1/(r + 1)^2))) ) r^2 (r + 1)^9 (r - 1)^9 g^2 ]
```

> ```
> g^2 (-1 + r^2)^9 (-b^2 + r^2) + 8 r^2 (-1 + r^2)^6 Σ^3 
> - 8/15 r^2 (5 + 45 r^2 + 63 r^4 + 15 r^6) Σ^9
> ```

So let's define:

```
p[r_, Σ_, b_, g_] := (   g^2 (-1 + r^2)^9 (-b^2 + r^2) + 8 r^2 (-1 + r^2)^6 Σ^3
                       - 8/15 r^2 (5 + 45 r^2 + 63 r^4 + 15 r^6) Σ^9 )
```

it is a polynomial in its all varables:

```
PolynomialQ[ #, Variables @ #]& @ p[r, Σ, b, g]
```

> ```
> True
> ```

Now we can simply look for cases where `CountRoots` finds more real roots than `4`

```
Manipulate[ CountRoots[p[r, Σ, b, g], r], 
           { Σ, -10, 10}, {b, -2, 0}, {g, -2.5, 2.5}]
```

[image]

Now it is much simpler to provide an example with rational arguments e.g.

```
CountRoots[ p[ r, 23/10, 8323/1001, 1/20], r]
```

> ```
> 8
> ```

Therefore we conclude that there are cases with more than `4` real roots of the equation. Evaluating e.g.

```
NSolve[p[r, 23/10, 8323/1001, 1/20] == 0, r, Reals]
```

we can check that the roots are all distinct.

Moreover we can plot the region where we have more that `4` real roots (`p` as a `20`-th order polynomial in `r` has `20` complex roots). For the sake of speed we can use this option `PerformanceGoal -> "Speed"` in `RegionPlot3D` (nontheless it takes > `1` minute to evaluate):

```
RegionPlot3D[ CountRoots[p[r, Σ, b, g], r] > 4,
              {Σ, -2.5, 2.5}, {b, -10, 10}, {g, -2.5, 2.5}, PerformanceGoal -> "Speed"]
```

[image]

The structure of the region of interest seems to be more sophisticated but plotting it with higher fidelity needs much more time.

**Edit**

Working with `Manipulate` we can also provide examples where there are `20` real roots, e.g.:

```
CountRoots[ p[r, 0, 1, 1], r]
```

> ```
> 20
> ```

though in general there are multiple roots:

```
 r /. Solve[ p[r, 0, 1, 1] == 0, r, Reals]
```

> ```
> {-1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1}
> ```

i.e. `1` is a `10`-fold root:

```
 Count[ %, 1]
```

> ```
> 10
> ```

Comment: "The structure of the region of interest seems to be more sophisticated" [Indeed](http://i.stack.imgur.com/Uqta8.png)...

Comment: I wish that plot would be better as well...

Comment: [Voilà](http://i.stack.imgur.com/lvpqq.png).

Comment: @RahulNarain could you post the parameters you used to generate that plot.

Comment: @rcollyer: It's just Artes's `RegionPlot3D` with `PlotPoints -> 100` and a very long time. The other difference is that the plot in Artes's answer seems to have been rotated by 90 degrees clockwise about the $z$ axis.

Answer (score 10):

Applying the experimental method, we can see that the conjecture is false. Let

```
{\[CapitalSigma], g, b} = {-8.12029, 4.79026, 1.46801}
```

Then solve for the roots:

```
NSolve[1 - (b/r)^2 - g^-2*(2/15*\[CapitalSigma]^9 
     (1/(r - 1)^9 - 1/(r + 1)^9 - 9/(8 r) (1/(r - 1)^8 - 1/(r + 1)^8)) - 
     \[CapitalSigma]^3 (1/(r - 1)^3 - 1/(r + 1)^3 - 3/(2 r) (1/(r - 1)^2 - 
     1/(r + 1)^2))) == 0, r]
```

to which the answer is a long string of 20 complex values. On the other hand, let

```
{\[CapitalSigma], g, b} = {2.34665, 0.0507719, 8.31449}
```

Then the above has 8 real roots (and 12 complex roots). So you can have either (i) fewer than four real roots or (ii) more than 4 real roots, depending on the values.

Comment: +1 for tenacity or luck.  I tried several values but got "only 4" (i.e. <= 4).  Should have automated it, I guess.

Comment: @Michael E2 -- It was neither luck not tenacity, I had Mathematica guess 10000 cases and count (and print) the number of times there were not 4 real roots. This is the kind of "proof" computers are really good at.

Comment: Following up, it took me more than 10000 cases, but Artes' answer shows that one will have more luck in some regions than others.